# Equality of sets with square-free integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say we have $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] = \{a+b\sqrt{d} | a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] = \{a+b\sqrt{d} | a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for square-free integers $d$. I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]_S$ (here $S$ is the set of multiplicative nonzero integers).

In my head it logically makes sense, but I cannot think of how to formalize this proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Equality of sets is two containments. For one of them, a common denominator shall be used.

Comment: Presumably you mean "$S$ is the multiplicatively closed set comprising the non-zero integers" and "$R_S$" means the localisation of the ring $R$ at the set $S$, i.e., the ring that extends $R$ by adding in inverses for the elements of $S$. So what's the problem?

Comment: @RobArthan The problem was my misunderstanding of notation. I had thought $R_s$ meant the ring evaluated at those values - big mistake. Thank you!